# Leaflet (geojson) mouseover don't work

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, mouseevent, mouseover, geojson

I am having problems attaching mouseover, mouseout and click events to leaflet geojson features. I cannot make them work.

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import L from 'leaflet';
import $ from 'jquery';
    L.Icon.Default.imagePath = '.';
    L.Icon.Default.mergeOptions({
    iconRetinaUrl: require('leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon-2x.png'),
    iconUrl: require('leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon.png'),
    shadowUrl: require('leaflet/dist/images/marker-shadow.png'),
    });
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }  
  componentDidMount() {
    var map = L.map('mapcontainer').setView([40, 0], 2);
    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?{foo}', {foo: 'bar'}).addTo(map);
    var i=0;
    function getColor(i) {
      // for "random colors"
      return  i > 20   ? '#ff5555: '#ffee00';
    }    
    function style(i) {
      return {
        fillColor: getColor(i),
        weight: 2,
        opacity: 1,
        color: 'white',
        dashArray: '3',
        fillOpacity: 0.7
      };
    }    
    function highlightFeature(e) {
      var layer = e.target;
      layer.setStyle({fillColor: '#ff0000',fillOpacity: 1,weight: 5,opacity: 1,color: '#666',dashArray: ''});
      if (!L.Browser.ie && !L.Browser.opera && !L.Browser.edge) {layer.bringToFront();}
    }    
    function highlight (layer) {
        layer.setStyle({
          weight: 5,
          color: 'black'
        });
        if (!L.Browser.ie && !L.Browser.opera) {
            layer.bringToFront();
        }
    }    
    function notsohighlight (layer) {
        layer.setStyle({
          weight: 2,
          color: 'white'
        });
    }    
    var layer;
    $.getJSON('./data/world.geojson', function(geojson) {
      var i=0;
      layer = L.geoJson(geojson, {
          onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
            layer.setStyle(style(i));
            if (i<20) { 
              layer.on({
                'mouseover': function (e) {
                  highlight(e.target);
                },
                'mouseout': function (e) {
                    notsohighlight(e.target);
                }
              });
            }
            if (i===50) {
              layer.on({
                mouseover: "alert('xxx')"
              });
            } 
            if (i===1 || i===20 || i===50) {
              // for check layer._events
              console.log('i:'+i+' country:'+feature.properties.name+' layer._events:'+JSON.stringify(layer._events));
              // i:1 country:Angola layer._events:{"mouseover":[{}],"mouseout":[{}]}
              // i:20 country:Belize layer._events:undefined
              // i:50 country:Spain layer._events:{"mouseover":[{"fn":"alert('xxx')"}]}
            }
            i++;
          }
      }).addTo(map)
    });  
  }
  render() {
        var mapStyle = {
            height: '600px',
            width: '1000px',
            margin: '0 auto'
        };    
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
          <h2>Leaflet</h2>
        </div>
        <div id="mapcontainer" style={mapStyle}></div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

From here you can see what is on layer._events 
(I would guess that I need to get right code here):
// i:1 country:Angola layer._events:{"mouseover":[{}],"mouseout":[{}]}
// i:20 country:Belize layer._events:undefined
// i:50 country:Spain layer._events:{"mouseover":[{"fn":"alert('xxx')"}]}

So for if i is under 20 i have:

```
layer.on({
  'mouseover': function (e) {
    highlight(e.target);
}
```

So it is at least trying to put something there. For testing reasons I didn't try to put anything above 20 (except 50).

And for i = 50 (just something for test, mouseover should work like it is on i<20. but at least there is something)

```
layer.on({
  mouseover: "alert('xxx')"
});
```

I am making react app, but haven't managed to make react-leaflet work neither. Couldn't attach geojson at all to it. So if I could get this work it would be nice start (and maybe I don't need react-leaflet at all?

Here is geojson i have used with this:
https://github.com/johan/world.geo.json/blob/master/countries.geo.json?short_path=64005ce

I would be very happy if someone could help me here. Thanks!

Comment: which version of leaflet you are trying ?

Comment: Package.json says "^1.0.2"

Comment: if it's Leaflet v1 then use L.geoJSON and not v.07's L.geoJson . See http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#geojson

Comment: Changed L.geoJson to L.geoJSON, no change.